# c++ simple stream manipulation with ostream and istream?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream, cout

I have been looking for a solution but couldn't find what I need/want.

All I want to do is pass a stream intended for std::cout to a function, which manipulates it. What I have used so far is a template function:

```
template<typename T>
void printUpdate(T a){
   std::cout << "blabla" << a << std::flush;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ){

  std::stringstream str;
  str << " hello " << 1 + 4 << " goodbye";
  printUpdate<>( str.str() );

  return 0;
}
```

What I would prefer is something like:

```
printUpdate << " hello " << 1 + 4 << " goodbye";
```

or

```
 std::cout << printUpdate << " hello " << 1 + 4 << " goodbye";
```

I was trying to do:

```
void printUpdate(std::istream& a){
   std::cout << "blabla" << a << std::flush;
}
```

but that gave me:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘void(std::istream&) {aka void(std::basic_istream<char>&)}’ and ‘const char [5]’ to binary ‘operator<<’
```

Comment: You can't output data to an input stream.  Change the parameter to `std::ostream& a`.  Also, `flush` is not defined for input streams.

Comment: I've tried that as well. Same error:

error: invalid operands of types ‘void(std::ostream&) {aka void(std::basic_ostream<char>&)}’ and ‘const char [5]’ to binary ‘operator<<’

Comment: In your `main` function, you need to supply the stream type to `printUpdate` function call, such as `printUpdate<std::ostream>`.

Comment: Don't know exactly what you want. But if you want to do anything looking like `printUpdate() << "this is my output"` (mind the parentheses), you must return the stream from `printUpdate()`. If you want to do something fancy with the right-hand-side before pushing it to `std::cout` or you want to push something to std::cout after your content (as the content of printUpdate suggests), printUpdate should be a class with an overloaded `template <typename T> operator<<(T data)`. Then you can translate `printUpdate << "Bla"` into `std::cout << X << "Bla" << Y`, where `X` and `Y` are fixed.

Comment: @Oguk Thanks, so there probably is no simpler alternative to making printUpdate a class.

Comment: See my edit in my answer.  You may want to search for "stackoverflow tie cout".  I believe you want to tie two or more streams together so you send the same data to more than one stream.

Comment: @andreas_: well, only if you insist on the signature `printUpdate << "blabla"`. If you are fine with `printUpdate("blabla")` instead, you can use your function approach, as proposed by Thomas Matthews. Edit: just saw the answer by Thomas is going in a different direction (outputting to two streams simultaneously). Is this what you want? I thought your question is just how to use a "stream-like" syntax for outputting your update, that automatically adds some fixed stuff around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't output data to an input stream, just not a good thing to do.
Change:

```
void printUpdate(std::istream& a){
   std::cout << "blabla" << a << std::flush;
}
```

To:

```
void printUpdate(std::ostream& a){
   std::cout << "blabla" << a << std::flush;
}
```

Note the stream type change.

**Edit 1:**
Also, you can't output a stream to another stream, at least `std::cout`.
The return value of `<< a` is a type `ostream`.
The `cout` stream doesn't like being fed another stream.

Change to:

```
void printUpdate(std::ostream& a)
{
  static const std::string text = "blabla";
  std::cout << text << std::flush;
  a << text << std::flush;
}
```

**Edit 2:**
You need to pass a stream to a function requiring a stream.
**You can't pass a string to a function requiring a stream.**
Try this:

```
  void printUpdate(std::ostream& out, const std::string& text)
  {
    std::cout << text << std::flush;
    out << text << std::flush;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    std::ofstream my_file("test.txt");
    printUpdate(my_file, "Apples fall from trees.\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

**Chaining Output Streams**
If you want to chain things to the output stream, like results from functions, the functions either have to return a printable (streamable object) or the same output stream.

Example:

```
  std::ostream& Fred(std::ostream& out, const std::string text)
  {
    out << "--Fred-- " << text;
    return out;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    std::cout << "Hello " << Fred("World!\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I've tried that as well. Same error:

error: invalid operands of types ‘void(std::ostream&) {aka void(std::basic_ostream<char>&)}’ and ‘const char [5]’ to binary ‘operator<<’

Comment: The error message doesn't match the example in my edit because `text` is a `std::string` not an array of 5 characters.

Comment: Sorry, the error message comes from the function call:
printUpdate << "abcd";